# UNIX - How to write a bash script to automatically change to next/previous directory

Tags: bash, unix, directory, cd

Say I have this folder structure:

```
MainFolder
    Folder1
    Folder2
    Folder3
    ...
    Folder200
```

I want to write a script that, if I am current inside Folder2 and execute the script, it will automatically change to the next directory in the list, in this case, Folder3. The restrictions are that the folders could have any name, and I cannot rename it.

So my questions are:

1) How can I know what directory is next on the list? I was wondering if the subdirectories of a directory have a sequential index number that I could use to know what dir comes next.

2) Since I would like to display the name of the new directory at the end of the script, is there a way to display only the dir name? (eg: Folder3 instead of /home/path/to/dir/Folder3 which is the result of "pwd")

Comment: Can it be assumed that each folder has only one folder inside it?

Comment: Note that you have to source the script, otherwise it will run in a subshell and be unable to change the current shell's current directory.

Comment: or better, use a shell function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What defines the order in which the directories are to be processed?  If you have directories without spaces and other special characters in their names, you can use `ls` to list the directories in order, and then find the name after the current directory:

   ```
   cwd=$(basename $PWD)
   nwd=$(ls .. | awk "/^$cwd$/ { found = 1; next; } { if (found) { print; found = 0 } }")
   if [ -d ../$nwd ]
   then cd ../$nwd
   fi
   ```
2. The name of the directory (only) is found using `basename $PWD` or `${PWD##*/}`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I see that the script should be working, however when I try sourcing it, I receive the message "Illegal variable name". Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Why would you be sourcing a script like this?    The only possible 'illegal variable name' that I can see would be `${PWD##*/}` which is indeed an invalid name if your shell isn't `bash` and doesn't recognize the `##` notation.  I still use `basename` because I learned it over a quarter century ago and it still works.  If it's still a problem, instead of sourcing the script, use `bash -x script` to see what it is doing (without affecting your current shell).  Then come back with a report (the output of the `bash -x script`) on where the trouble is if you can't see what it is yourself.

Comment: I used bash -x script and fixed a typo in my script (thanks for introducing the debugger to me). However, although the script is shown to be working in the debugger, it runs on a subshell and therefore dont really change the directory. I tried sourcing it and thats when I get the Illegal variable name error message. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like your shell isn't actually bash?  If `bash -x script` works correctly and your shell is `bash`, then you should be safe to source it.  I've not come across a situation where that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming the sequence has no holes.

```
cdn()
{
  cd ${PWD%%[0-9]*}$(( $(echo $PWD | sed 's/.*[^0-9]//')+1))
}
```

Edit: it seems I overlooked the "directory could have any name" statement. From your example, I assumed they have a trailing numerical id ...

It would have been clearer if you had put random names instead of Folderxx in your example.

Edit2: Here is a shell function that suits your requirements:

```
cdn()
{
    for i in $(echo "/\/$(basename $PWD)$/
+1,\$p
Q" | ed -s !"ls -d ../*" | tail -n +2)
    do
        \cd $i 2>/dev/null && echo $(basename $PWD) && break
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the confusion!